# Yii2 ActiveDateProvider and joinWith hasMany relation

Tags: yii2

I use ActiveDateProvider and I use query like this:

```
Foo::find()->joinWith('relation');
```

And Foo's relation is hasMany, so there is more than one record joined to every Foo.

In that case the pagination doesn't work properly (for example in GridView it says: **Showing 1-6 of 17 items.** even though the pagination is set to 10 and there are actually only 10 records of Foo in the database)

What can I do to make the pagination work properly (counting only Foo, not the joined records)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply, but I recently stuck into the issue and found out that `distinct()`  will do the trick for you.

```
Foo::find()->joinWith('relation')->distinct();
```